# FilePicker.IO & Meteor (Multiple Widgets on a Page)

Tags: meteor, filepicker.io

I am using FilePicker.IO with Meteor.  I have it set up and working, but I have fun into an issue using multiple widgets on a page.

I have a table with rows of data.  The data set is a bunch of users with name, photo, address, etc.

I'd like to include a "upload photo" button on EACH row, but since the widget is rendered by ID, I am limited to one per page.  Wondering if there is a solution where I can have an upload widget on each row of the table.

Here is my code in my coffee file:

```
filepicker.setKey('askdjw&H*(Djkjew)')  #Not my key

Template.admin.rendered = () ->  
    filepicker.constructWidget $('#uploadPhoto')
```

HTML:

```
<td><input type="filepicker-dragdrop" id="uploadPhoto" class="{{_id}}"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things :

- if `{{_id}}` is a unique id it should be in the id attribute
- it looks like you are just passing a jQuery selector into filepicker, what is stopping you from using `$('.uploadPhoto')` instead?

[You can see a similar pattern here in my `datatables` implementation](https://github.com/austinrivas/origin-ui/blob/master/client/tables/dynamicTables.js#L89)

Comment: Yep, I tried the uploadPhoto class originally as there are multiple rows, but no luck with that solution unfortunately.